# Manuscript submitted to Crelle's journal without acknowledgement

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics

I submitted a manuscript to Crelle's journal about a month ago but never received a confirmation email from the editor whom I emailed the manuscript. I sent him/her another email asking about the status of paper and never heard back. I was wondering if that is a common and that is how it works with them.

Comment: I don't have any direct experience with this particular journal but giving them a ring might help to clarify things. You may also want to e-mail other members of the editorial team.

Comment: I'm marked this as duplicate because I think the key elements of your question regarding communication and common practice, is answered in the linked canonical answer.  If there are more specific things that you want an answer for, please feel free to edit to focus on them and the question can be reopened.

Comment: I have dealt with Crelle's journal recently.  Some advice: I suggest submitting to the managing editor (he has a secretary).  If you've gotten no response at all after about a month, you should resubmit to the managing editor.  Whenever I have done this, I have always gotten a timely *something* in response....although strangely, almost every time the immediate response is that their office is unoccupied for a certain period, which can be about three weeks long!  But then they do always get back to me in a contentful way within a month.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark just emailed him and briefly went over my case. Received an email almost immediately saying  that he is "out" of office and he will be back on September 5th. I guess I am going to have to wait. Knowing the quality of my manuscript, submitting to Crelle's might be aiming too high and I am thinking the sooner I know about the fate of my paper, the better I can decide for my next move.

Comment: @BigM: You got the same message that I've gotten several times.  I would take it as a sign that things are back on track.  You have to be patient in dealing with journals....basically with all reputable math journals.  Notwithstanding the fact that seemingly no one is ever in the Crelle editorial office, I have found that they do their business rather well.

Comment: Finally the got back to me acknowledging the receipt of my manuscript. Now I will have to wait and see if the designated editor likes my paper.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark a side cliché question. Do they have a very long review process? My manuscript is very short.

Comment: @BigM: I have only submitted two papers to Crelle in my life, so the sample size is much too small for me to meaningfully address your question.  Moreover, almost any mathematics journal could have a long review process depending on the referee you get.  Most of the exceptions are actually very poor journals.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark after a few weeks I received a rejection letter from Crelle stating that the result wasn't strong enough. I managed to improve the results and rewrote the manuscript which of much higher quality now.I dared to submit it to Acta Math.if it will take them several months to referee the manuscript so be it. At this point I don't mind gambling.